# Python assign new row names to rows created by groupby

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataset, I summed values across columns using `groupby`, and attached the new summed values to the original dataframe like below.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Person':['A','B','C','D','E','F'], 
    'NY':[1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0],
    'LA':[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    'CHI':[2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    'Gender':['F','F','F','M','M','NA'],
    'Citizenship':['US','Canada','US','US','Mexico','Canada'],
    'Age':['30s','30s','50s','NA','20s','30s']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
n_by_gender = df.groupby(['Gender']).sum()
n_by_citizenship = df.groupby(['Citizenship']).sum()
n_by_age = df.groupby(['Age']).sum()
df_new = pd.concat([df, n_by_gender, n_by_citizenship, n_by_age])
```

I noticed that when I concatenate these dataframes, Python automatically creates an index that is related to the groups I assigned, but that these aren't actual row names (like the image below - from Jupyter notebook). Instead of hard-coding row names, is there a way to assign row names based on the index? (e.g. 7th, 8th and 9th row would be named `"Gender_F", "Gender_M", "Gender_NA"`, 10th and 11th row would be named `"Citizenship_Canada", "Citizenship_Mexico"`, ...) Would it be easier to create a new column named `ID` or something to store this information, instead of having them stored as row names?

[image]

Edit: final dataframe would look like this:

```
final = {'rownames':['NY','LA','CHI'],
         'Gender_F':[2,1,0],
         'Gender_M':[3,1,0],
         'Gender_NA':[0,1,1],
         'Citizenship_Canada':[1,2,1],
         'Citizenship_Mexico':[0,1,0],
         'Citizenship_US':[4,1,3],
         'Age_20s':[0,1,0],
         'Age_30s':[2,2,3],
         'Age_50s':[0,1,1],
         'Age_NA':[3,0,0]}
finaldf = pd.DataFrame(final)
finaldf
```

Comment: What the reason, you are filtering and concatenating to the same dataframe?

Comment: Eventually I want to  throw out rows that contain individual information (`A`, `B`, `C`, ...), then transpose the dataframe so that I have `NY`, `LA` and `CHI` as rows, and all the sums I calculated (`F`, `M`, `NA`, ...) as columns.

Comment: Ok, can you give us a sample of your expected output? Who know, there maybe a simple approach

Comment: @wwnde Just added the final dataframe I'm hoping to produce!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In summary, use `.melt` to unpivot the dataframe into a long format, `pd.get_dummies` to create dummy variable columns, `np.where`, and `.groupby`.

1. First, `.melt` the dataframe and specify all of the columns that you are NOT eventually grouping by, so pass all the columns to the `id_vars` parameter that are not 'NY', 'LA' or 'CHI'. A 'variable' column is automatically created with a corresponding 'value' column transforming the data from a wide format (i.e. pivoted format) to a long format (i.e. unpivoted format).
2. Second use `pd.get_dummies()` and pass the columns that you want dummy variables for and specify the `dtype` as 'int' in preparation for the next step. Alternatively, you can use the default `dtype` for `pd.get_dummies()`, which is `np.uint8`, but I find it easier to just pass `dtype='int'`.
3. In the third step, I loop through the relevant columns (all columns that are of dtype 'int' except the 'value' column) and use `np.where()` to apply the 'value' column to any cells that returned a 1 when we did `pd.get_dummies()` earlier.
4. Finally, you are ready to do a .groupby() of the 'variable' column, summarizing the data by the three cities ('NY', 'LA', 'CHI').

   ```
   import pandas as pd, numpy as np
   df1 = df.melt(id_vars=['Person', 'Gender', 'Citizenship', 'Age'])
   a = pd.get_dummies(df1, columns=['Gender', 'Citizenship', 'Age'], dtype='int')
   for col in a.columns.to_list():
       if col != ['value'] and a[col].dtype == 'int':
           a[col] = np.where(a[col] == 1, a['value'], a[col])
   b = a.groupby('variable').sum().reset_index().rename({'variable' : 'rownames'}, axis=1).drop('value', axis=1)
   b
   ```